# Complete payment using window.open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, iframe

I'm using a payment processor which gives me a URL to send the user to. I can specify success_url, cancel_url parameters which the user will be redirected to after the payment. The problem is, my app is a react app and I don't want to reload the page. I want to create a flow where the payment page url will be opened using window.open and from the React app I could track the state of the payment using window.postMessage. Is it the right approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like that should work just fine so long as the post processing urls are on the same domain as the opener window.  I would also add a success/fail response *back to the new window* and call window.close so the popup goes away.

My only concern is popup blockers might block the popup, but so long as you call `window.open` as a result of a user action (eg click) it should work just fine.

A solution that should circumvent that problem would be for you to open the link in an iframe on the page - with the rest of the flow the same (window.postMessage handshake, then remove iframe) - but if the payment processor employs some sort of iframe busting then this won't work.

Good luck!